# Elasticsearch - Count distinct

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have a basic index with logs

Some logs are visit of user1 to user2

I managed to count the total of visits a user has received, but I don't know how count the total of distinct users a user has received[image]

This is giving me all the logs for a user

```
{
    "post_filter":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {
                    "term":{
                        "message":"visit"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term":{
                        "ctxt_user2":"733264"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "query":{
        "match_all":{}
    }
}
```

Actually, I'm using FoSElasticaBundle for Symfony2

```
$filter->addMust((new Term())->setTerm('message', 'visit'));
$filter->addMust((new Term())->setTerm('ctxt_user2', $this->search->getVisit()));
```

I read some pages in the ES doc with aggregator, but I never managed to get what I want

Convert to SQL, I just need

```
SELECT COUNT(DISCTING ctxt_user1)
FROM logs
WHERE ctxt_user2 = 733264
```

**EDIT:**

Cardinality seams to be what I need.
Now just need to find how use it with FosElasticaBundle

```
"aggs": {
    "yourdistinctcount": {
        "cardinality": {
            "field": "ctxt_user1"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query ( not tested...):

```
{
"query" : {
 "bool":{
         "must":[
             {
                 "term":{
                     "message":"visit"
                }
            },
            {
                "term":{
                    "ctxt_user2":"733264"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
  "yourdistinctcount": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "ctxt_user1"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The `post_filter` query cannot be used in your case. As it write on Elastic.co website: The `post_filter` is applied to the search hits at the very end of a search request, after aggregations have already been calculated.`

HtH,

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the 3 lines which contains "733264" in ctxt_user2 :(

Comment: the result is located on the aggs result not on the hits. If you want to disable search result add "size":0 before "query"

Comment: Oh, didn't know that!
But 
    "aggregations": {
        "yourdistinctcount": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                "key": 18475,
                "doc_count": 3
                }
            ]
        }        
    }